# Why are duplicate rows not allowed in a relational database?

Tags: database, jdbc, rdbms

In [this introductory tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html) on JDBC and Relational Databases, it is stated,

> **Integrity Rules**
>
> Relational tables follow certain integrity rules to ensure that the
>   data they contain stay accurate and are always accessible. First, the
>   rows in a relational table should all be distinct. **If there are
>   duplicate rows, there can be problems resolving which of two possible
>   selections is the correct one.**

But if the rows are duplicate, it means all the fields in both the rows hold the same values; and when they are completely same (duplicate), how does the question of one being correct and the other being incorrect arise? **How does the duplication of a row harm the data integrity?**

Comment: When you have to change one of the values of the row, which row changes?  Why do you have duplicate rows in your table?  What does the duplication represent?

Comment: Pedantically, duplicates are a bad idea in an operational database (like an e-commerce store), but are fine in a data warehouse, both of which can use a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason could be:

1. Wastage of space for maintaining duplicate records which doesn't make sense.
2. Unnecessary wastage of memory space (main memory) when you select data in your application.
3. Normalization Constraint: if your table has duplicate records then it's not a normalized table at all.
4. If 2 record exists for a single person then it's really confusing cause there could be one more customer with same name, address etc. Example: Bank customer.

So if you don't define a way to distinctly identify the person then how will you say that the account X belongs to which person.

Answer (score 2):

That is a kind of a philosophical question. But I think you might be putting too much into it. I would say that the problem is really "How does the data base know which row is the correct to fetch". In one of the first systems I set up, I messed with the keys and managed to get duplicate rows in the table. Then the problem was how to tell the db which rows to get rid of (20 years ago, using postgres 5.x I think). It does per se not harm the data integrety, but it harms "accurate and always accessible" as it is not possible to fetch just the one row that you need.

An example: if someone makes a person table like

```
create table person(
   name varchar not null,
   dateofbirth date not null,
   town varchar not null);
```

it is clear that you are going to get duplicate records sooner or later. I know that the first John Smith born 31.08.67 living in Oslo is my old class mate, whereas the second John Smith born 31.08.67 living in Oslo is the colleague I met first time a week ago. But I have no possibility to tell them from each other in the data base and I have no possibility to handle them separately. So if i later do a

```
alter table person add connection;
```

then I would not have any possibility to put the correct data into the database system.

Answer (score 1):

Data integrity, the question one would have to ask is why would two identical records be allowed in a table, for what purpose does that serve.

How would you know which record your talking about? Lets take identical twins for example, they may match in every way but their names, in this way we can identify to which person we are talking to.

duplication of rows breaks data integrity because it breaks the founding rules set up by RDBMS.

if duplication occurred, you would not be able to relate to a specific set of data, which is the stated objective of RDBMS as stated in your question post.

technically you can have multiple rows with the same data, the caveat is that you must include a primary key which differentiates your rows.

Hope this makes sense and helps